# How do I avoid Android always for Bluetooth permission when running BTDemo

Tags: bluetooth, codenameone

The CN1BlueToothle is really great, but every time I run the demo Android asks to allow the demo to use Bluetooth.

The project file includes the necessary
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" / >
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" / >

Is there anything else that needs to be in the codenameone_library_appended.properties?

It would be good to add a "Disable" button to the demo so that you don't have to restart your device after closing the demo.

Answer (score 1):

The initialize method contains a parameter "request" that prompts the user to enable Bluetooth.